# Azure Pipeline Locked By Testhost

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Has anyone experienced the Azure pipeline issue when running the dotnet test?
I'm currently using .Net 5 as the target framework.
And I encounter this issue below.

```
 warning MSB3026: Could not copy "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\microsoft.testplatform.objectmodel\16.9.4\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.dll" to "..\..\..\build\bin\net5.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.dll". Beginning retry 7 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'D:\a\1\s\BE\build\bin\net5.0\Microsoft.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.dll' because it is being used by another process. The file is locked by: "testhost (4240)"
```

I have already install .NET 5 version 5.0.x

and include Nuget Install Tool version 5.8

Comment: I get similar errors with only 1 of my csprojs in the Azure build pipeline where it perpetually fails with a message:  ##[warning]C:\Users\VssAdministrator\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\4.2.0\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(70,5): Warning MSB3026: Could not copy "...\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll" to "...\bin\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll".  The file is being used by another process.    
Could it be caused by a project dependency ALSO depending on this dll and msbuild is trying to restore them at the same time - i.e. a thread race on this file ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the underlying cause is identical to this post and the solution is the same -  to add the `--maxcpucount:1` argument to whichever command is failing due to race condition on the resource (file).

[DotNet 6.0 publish error MSB4018: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74025755/dotnet-6-0-publish-error-msb4018-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it/75247123)