# Azure build pipeline fails with error 'The process cannot access the file '...' because it is being used by another process.'

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

Intermittent failure of build stage of a csproj in an Azure pipeline (DotNetCoreCLI@2).

Sometimes simply repeating the step will succeed other times it fails repeatedly.

Exact error message for me was:

> [warning]C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\4.2.0\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(70,5): Warning MSB3026: Could not copy "D:\a\1\s\publish_output\RectangularChamber\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll" to "D:\a\1\s\publish_output\RectangularChamber\bin\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'D:\a\1\s\publish_output\RectangularChamber\bin\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll' because it is being used by another process.
> C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\4.2.0\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(70,5): warning MSB3026: Could not copy "D:\a\1\s\publish_output\RectangularChamber\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll" to "D:\a\1\s\publish_output\RectangularChamber\bin\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'D:\a\1\s\publish_output\RectangularChamber\bin\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll' because it is being used by another process.  [D:\a\1\s_Assets\AccessCover\src\AccessCover.csproj]
> ##[error]C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\4.2.0\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): Error : System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\a\1\s\publish_output\RectangularChamber\Register\function.json' because it is being used by another process.

Hard to replicate reliably.
The issue is somewhat further documented in this closed github but they don't resolve it.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/32219

Have found other SO posts that are a little related but most relate to VS builds rather than Azure pipeline builds so posting this as a new question as it more precisely documents this build fail and hopefully will help more people find the solution more directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause and the solution is documented on this SO [DotNet 6.0 publish error MSB4018: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74025755/dotnet-6-0-publish-error-msb4018-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it/75247123) albeit the issue discussed is slightly different .

The solution is to add the argument `--maxcpucount:1` to the command in your pipeline that is failing.  It explicitly tells the Azure agent to use a single thread for the stage that is failing for you.  Limiting the stage to be run on a single thread like this prevents a race on the resource or file that is being locked out by a competing thread.

Here is an example of what the fix looks like in my own pipeline (see final line 'arguments:'):

```
  # Build, archive and publish the project artifact
  - job: BuildArchivePublish
    displayName: 'Build, Archive and Publish'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Build'
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: |
          $(workingFolderA)/*.csproj
        arguments: --maxcpucount:1 --output $(publishFolder) --configuration Release /nowarn:CS0162,CS0168,CS0612,CS0618,CS1570,CS1572,CS1573,CS1711,CS1735,CS8632 /clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;ErrorsOnly /verbosity:quiet
```

I think MS should better resolve this issue so that the race condition is properly handled - instead i think they closed the thread here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/32219 without addressing this problem properly.  Happy to be wrong if someone knows better.